# VirtualHost configuration issue

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wsgi, mod-alias

I have two apps I want to serve via port 80 in Apache on the same ip host. To do so, I have defined the following virtual hosts:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wsgi/rest_api"
    ServerName api

    WSGIDaemonProcess rest_api user=gms  threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/wsgi/rest_api/rest_api.wsgi
    WSGIPassAuthorization On


    <Directory /var/www/wsgi/rest_api/rest_api>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Options  +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/extjs/cardiocatalogqt"
    ServerName cardiocatalogqt
    Alias /cardiocatalogqt /var/www/extjs/cardiocatalogqt
    <Directory /var/www/extjs/cardiocatalogqt>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that only the first one in the list is being recognized (they both work independently). What am I missing to get both of these working together, independent of order?

**EDIT**

I am trying to avoid use of different server names due to a CORS authentication issue across domains (which includes host names and ports). All I want is two different paths as such to resolve accordingly: http://test.com/cardiocatalogqt and http://test.com/api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_alias was what I wanted, ala http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Works like a charm!

**EDIT**

More specifically, my config looks like this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess rest_api user=gms  threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /api /var/www/wsgi/rest_api/rest_api.wsgi
WSGIPassAuthorization On

<Directory /var/www/wsgi/rest_api/rest_api>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options  +Indexes
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/extjs/cardiocatalogqt"
    ServerName cardiocatalogqt
    Alias /cardiocatalogqt /var/www/extjs/cardiocatalogqt
    <Directory /var/www/extjs/cardiocatalogqt>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please create two different virtual host with different server names and different document root paths

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, add the server name into the hosts file.

Comment: I am wondering if mod_alias is the way to go with this. Not sure how to implement the wsgi stuff without a virtual host though.

Comment: I upvoted for your answer, since it got me on track to search for the correct solution.